# Copying SSH Key From Root To Another User On Same Machine

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I am trying to create a server setup script. On initialization of the server, I add my ssh key which then gives me access to the root user via ssh. I now have created another user and gave them sudo access. Now I am trying to figure out how I can copy my SSH key from root user to the new user I just created. Both users are on the same machine and one is root and the other is a sudo user.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is just one of a few different ways to do this. I am assuming you've just created your user and it has `sudo` access.

1. Create the folder if it doesn't already exist:

   `mkdir /home/$USER/.ssh`
2. Make the directory only executable by the user:

   `chmod 700 /home/$USER/.ssh`
3. Copy the `authorized_keys` file that contains your public key:

   `sudo cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. Make everything in `.ssh` owned by your user:

   `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.ssh`
5. Make it readable only by your user:

   `sudo chmod 600 /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys`

If your user does NOT have `sudo` access, you can modify this workflow a bit. Using your user name instead of `<user>`, run these as root:

```
mkdir /home/<user>/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/<user>/.ssh
cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R <user>:<user> /home/<user>/.ssh
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much it worked like charm. Thank you for your time and response!

Comment: Great, glad to be able to help

Comment: Go through this all the time when creating DO droplets

Comment: thanks for the note on how to do it for non-sudo users (: btw, chmod 600 = u+rw (or user read/write) and 700 = u+rwx (read/write/execute) permissions. newer OSes support eg `chmod u+rw` and I find it more readable and easier to use than calculating the 7xx values (: